# Is there a way to speed up maven-dependency-plugin copy

Tags: java, maven, build

I am using the maven-dependency-plugin to download an artifact from nexus:

```
mvn -f pom.xml org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:copy -Dartifact=my-artifact:1.0-SNAPSHOT:tar -DoutputDirectory=/output-dir
```

This works, but it takes a long time as it resolves and downloads many other dependencies. Is there a way to only download the artifact which is specified?

Thanks

Comment: It should be much faster the second time you run it due to caching.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but this is part of the setup of a docker image and only happens once. Thanks..

Comment: The first time it runs it must resolve all of its own dependencies unless they are already in the local repository. So you should avoid to always run the command with a blank local repository.